# How to set the Jupyter default user for Pyspark in GCP Dataproc

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

In a Jupyter notebook connected to a GCP Spark cluster, the cell `!pip3 install pyLDAvis==3.2.1` works, but gives a warning:

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. 
It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

The warning is not unique to `pyLDAvis`, other packages — even `numpy` — give the same warning.

Running the notebook as `root` shouldn't be the default. How can the default user in the notebook be set to `singhj` rather than `root`? I have searched through [IPython Configuration and customization](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/index.html) for any hints.

Configuration: Fresh cluster in GCP Dataproc, default Jupyter notebook, nothing customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jupyter server in a Dataproc cluster is run by the systemd service defined in the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service`.

If you want to change the user it runs as, then you can modify that file and replace the line saying `User=root` with one saying the name of the user you want (e.g. `User=singhj` in your example).

Then, once the file has been updated, restart the systemd service by running the following commands as root:

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload 
systemctl restart jupyter
```

If you want to automate that, you can write an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) to make the change at cluster creation time.

Comment: You'll have to also make sure your user has access to all of the required directories.

This can include:

/etc/jupyter, /etc/default/jupyter, /opt/dataproc/jupyter, /opt/conda/miniconda3/share/jupyter, /opt/conda/anaconda/share/jupyter, /var/log/jupyter, /var/log/jupyter_notebook.log

... where the exact set varies based on Dataproc image version.